# Is there any way to handle grafana loading embedded panels?

Tags: grafana

I'm new to using Grafana, and I would like to know if there is any way to determine when Grafana's embedded panels are loaded. I'm using Vue 3 on the frontend, where I embed the panels' IFrames, and there are multiple panels on a single page, around 20–25 panels. This causes the loading to be slow due to the requests that Grafana has to make for each panel to the backend.

I would like to add a loader to the page to give the impression that the panels are being loaded. I'm wondering if there is any event or something that Grafana can emit to let me know that the panels are loaded. Despite Grafana having its own loader, even that takes a few seconds to appear after the page loads.

I tried searching, but I couldn't find anything. If anyone knows of any tricks or ways to deal with this, I appreciate it in advance.